# `separate()` function from tidyr splitting on space instead of pattern

Tags: r, tidyr, separator

From a string with state and county information, I would like to split into two columns, from state and county. Using the function `separate`, even using the patter `","`, or variants as `"[,]"`, `"[\\,]"`, and `"\\,"`, but I continue to have my string split on the space, instead of the patter.

See example

```
data.frame(test = c("montana,sheridan",
                    "north dakota,divide",
                    "new york,clinton")) %>%
  separate(test, c("state", "county"), by=",", extra = "drop")
```

Comment: The argument is `sep` instead of `by`.  Checking the `?separate`, the Usage is `separate(data, col, into, sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+", remove = TRUE,
  convert = FALSE, extra = "warn", fill = "warn", ...)`

Comment: yep... I tried to go with more complicates solution, but was a very basic problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting wrong arguments. Use `sep = ","` not `by = ","`.

```
test = c("montana,sheridan",
     "north dakota,divide",
     "new york,clinton")
data.frame(test) %>%
     separate(test, c("state", "county"),
     sep=",", extra = "drop")
```

This worked for me. I hope you find this helpful.